# OpenCV stitcher ignores additional image

Tags: python, opencv, image-manipulation, panoramas, opencv-stitching

As a follow-up to the closed question ' [How to update a part of a panorama](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75727432/how-to-update-a-part-of-a-panorama) ' I have come up with an approach but OpenCV doesn't behave the way I want it to. To be more exact:

- I have a panorama of which I do not have the original images
- I have a new additional, smaller image that fits well into the panorama (except for warping, size adjustments etc) but has some more items in it that I want to be present in the adjusted panorama

The approach I am now on is to cut the panorama into several overlapping images and use those images together with the new image to stitch a new panorama. However, the new image is never part of the new panorama. Here is the code:

```
import cv2
from empatches import EMPatches

pano_img = cv2.imread('pano.jpg')
pano_height = pano_img.shape[0]
new_img = cv2.imread('new.jpg')

# Use the EMPatches lib to extract overlapping images. This works perfectly fine. 
# img_patches is a list of np.array, usable in OpenCV
emp = EMPatches()
img_patches, _ = emp.extract_patches(pano_img, pano_height, overlap=0.4)

img_patches.append(new_img)

stitcher = cv2.Stitcher_create()
status, output = stitcher.stitch(img_patches)
# Returns status 0 and output is the original panorama perfectly stitched.
# The new image was ignored.
```

I do not know where in the original panorama the new image would go, so I can't set up an order in the `img_patches` list if that's the issue. How can I tweak OpenCV to create the panorama containing the new image?

OpenCV is version 4.7.0.72 and installed using pip install opencv-python.

Panorama:
[image: The panorama]

New image:
[image: The new image to be integrated into the panorama]

Comment: Please post a reproducible example - post `pano.jpg` and `new.jpg`. The issue probably depends on the input images. In case you can't share the images, share some other panorama and image that reproduce the issue.

Comment: previous discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75727432/how-to-update-a-part-of-a-panorama

Comment: I'd try approaching this with feature matching. ideally you have some idea for the focal length. I'd formulate "rays" for all the feature points. for the panorama, you need the model. for the ordinary projective view (camera), you can either use focal length, or just guess it and then estimate the parameter explicitly from the matching. given the matched features and each point's ray, the rotation should be estimable. THEN you have a decent model and now you can warp the camera view into the panorama, and then you can compose that into the panorama, with suitable blending near the edges

Comment: the panorama isn't made all that accurate. vertical posts should appear vertical all throughout the "field of view" of the panorama. they don't. since that's the case (it's not a "simple" equirectangular mapping), matching the picture into this panorama may require nonlinear deformations, same as the panorama stitching did.